# Cross-Browser AJAX request with Basic Authentication

Tags: ajax, cross-browser

I'm currently trying to make a cross-browser AJAX request to return a stream from a networked video camera, however it always asks for a username and password even when they have been supplied.  I have also tried applying network credentials to a Uri in the backend code and sending the resulting Uri back to the page however that again asks for login.  The javascript is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
crossDomain: true,
//dataType: 'JSONP',
url: "@Url.Content("~/GetImage")",
data: {username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx' },
//username: 'xxx',
//password: 'xxx',
beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
   xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic"); 
},
success: function(data){
   alert(data);
   $('#CameraImage').attr('src', data);
 },
 error: function(error, status, thrownerror) {
    alert(thrownerror);
 }
});
```

I have tried various combinations of the above but to no avail (commented code).  I need to point the URL to the source of an image to display the stream.  Has anyone tried this sort of thing, and if so could point me in the right direction?

Many thanks for looking!!

Answer (score 0):

The below link will help you for sure if you use Java,

http://mytechbites.blogspot.in/2009/07/cross-domain-xmlhttprequest-calls.html